# Difference between joinWindows.of vs joinWindows.until in kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to understand the difference between joinWindows.of vs joinWindows.until while doing a left join. For example

```
Stream1.leftJoin(Stream2,SomeJoinerValue,joinWindows.of(2 mins).until(5 mins))
```

My understanding as per the documentation, as long as the time difference between Stream1 & Stream2 is less than 2 mins, a successful join will be performed without dropping anything from the streams.
My question here is, what is the use of windows retention period of 5 mins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window retention period is a lower bound for how log the window is kept and accepts new input data. This is required to handle out-of-order records. Joins are based on event-time and thus, it's not guaranteed that all records are processed in timestamp ordered. In fact, Kafka Streams processed records in offset order.

Comment: So, each stream has its own window retention period, or is it the common window for joined streams? Does it create any delay in the output stream?

Comment: Retention time applies to windows, not streams. Each windowed operator can have it's own retention time. And it does not create any additional latency -- data is processed immediately and latency is independent from retention time.